# Problem of marker click with Leaflet

Tags: r, leaflet, javascript, openstreetmap, rstudio

I am new using Leaflet with R studio and I have a problem ou both Leaflet markers and map_marker click .

The first problem is that , when I put addCircleMarkers in the observer in doesn't work while it works when I put it in the output.

The second one, I try to get the map_marker_click and to print it but it doesn't work . It seems like while clicking the map_marker_click is null.

Here is my code

```
    dataDepartementCas() %>%
      buildCasesDep(departements,centresDep)

  })
  

  dataDepartementCasTotalRecent <- reactive({
    dataDepartementCasTotal() %>% 
      filter(jour>max(dataDepartementCasTotal()$jour)+days(-30)) %>%
      group_by(dep,nom_departement,latitude,longitude) %>%
      summarise(P = sum(P),T=sum(T),pop = mean(pop),tauxIncidence = sum(P)/mean(pop)*100,
                tauxPositivite = sum(P)/sum(T)*100)
  })

 output$mapDepartement <- renderLeaflet({

   palInfectionF <- colorBin("Greens", domain = dataDepartementCasTotalRecent()$tauxIncidence)

    leaflet(dataDepartementCasTotalRecent()) %>%
      addTiles() %>%
      addLayersControl(
        position = "topright",
        overlayGroups = c("Cas","Tests","Hospitalisations","Deces à l'hôpital"),
        options = layersControlOptions(collapsed = FALSE))  %>%
      addProviderTiles(providers$CartoDB.Positron) %>%
      fitBounds(~-100,-60,~60,70) %>%
      addLegend("bottomleft", pal = palInfectionF, values = ~dataDepartementCasTotalRecent()$P,
                title = "<small>Infections</small>",group = "Infections") %>%
      hideGroup(c("Hospitalisations","Tests","Deces à l'hôpital")) %>%
      setView(lng = 2.213749, lat = 46.22764, zoom = 5) %>%
      addCircleMarkers(layerId = ~nom_departement,weight = 1, radius = ~P^(1/4),
                       fillOpacity = 0.7, color = "#777777", group = "Cas",fillColor = ~palInfectionF(tauxIncidence),
                       label = sprintf("<h4>%s</h4>Infections de 30 derniers jours :    <B>%s</B><br/>Taux d'incidence de 30 derniers jours:    <B>%s</B>",
                                       dataDepartementCasTotalRecent()$nom_departement,
                                       numberF(dataDepartementCasTotalRecent()$P),percentF(dataDepartementCasTotalRecent()$tauxIncidence)) %>% lapply(htmltools::HTML),
                       labelOptions = labelOptions(width = "50px",
                                                   style = list("font-weight" = "normal", padding = "3px 8px", "color" = lkp_blue),
                                                   textsize = "15px", direction = "auto"))
    })

observe({
    p <- input$map_marker_click$id
    mapClickDep <- p

    output$mapDepClick <- renderText({
      mapClickDep
    })
  })
```

The problem here is that I find nothing in output$mapDepClick.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Leaflet in R, but in JS Leaflet circle marker is not interactive by default, it has to be made interactive by `interactive: true` option.

Comment: Thank you , i'll see if I can do this. The problem that it is working in another leaflet map with another datatset with te same code

Answer (score 1):

The click_marker problem is resolved . I wrote map_marker_click while the nale of my map is "mapDepartement" . We must put "nameOfMap_marker_click" to get the right id .

But the problem of addMarkers that don't work if I put it in the observer is still there.